# What would a hypothetical lifeform in a universe with no electromagnetism look like?

Tags: electromagnetism, biophysics

I was watching an amazing [Arvin Ash video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT-6YVrecro&t=535s) in which he explained the purpose of light and speculated that life could possibly exist if the universe did not have the electromagnetic force but just strong, weak nuclear and gravity. Yet he didn’t know what that kind of life would look like and I am intrigued by the possibility. What would that look like?

Comment: This appears to be about speculative biology rather than the mainstream physics we deal with here. There is no site on the network which can possibly answer objectively. What would life in a universe *with* the electromagnetic force look like - see the huge variety of life on Earth. Even an answer to that question would be beyond the scope of any site.

Comment: To the contrary, this is a great question for Worldbuilding SE

Comment: Without electromagnetism there would be no Coulomb barrier, so the universe would be full of large nuclei with no electrons bound to them. How are you supposed to even get chemistry out of that, much less life?

Comment: @Tal, no. It's open-ended and lacks specificity - it comes across as a "fishing for ideas" type question. Such questions have been asked before and always get closed quickly until edited with lots of constraints. Please be wary of referring people to [worldbuilding.se] without also recommending they take the tour, read-up in the help centre about what's on-topic and how to approach wording their question *before* posting. (Also, to always include worldbuilding-context.)

Comment: There is no physics definition for life in terms of *this* universe's physics, let alone a hypothetical universe with physical laws we don't have a model for, let alone for life in *that* universe.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start, electromagnetism is responsible for holding particles together. While protons and neutrons are bound together by the nuclear force, electrons are attracted by the electromagnetic force. When you have no electrons, you can't form an atom. As a result, carbon, a crucial element for life, could never form, and life couldn't exist. If there were, however, some kind of hypothetical way to create life without full atoms, all you or anything that is living would be protons and neutrons.

Comment: See the old Sci Fi story Dragon's Egg by Robert Forward for life on a neutron star. But of course there is electromagnetic radiation present.